# Database query on month

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I query the total number of status per type of the current month and also query the total number of status of the future months to come. Both are separate queries. I looked up on the google but I had a hard time applying it.
I am using mysql.

my field names are

```
date                   status
format YYYY/MM/DD      PENDING, ACCEPTED, REJECTED
```

I tried to use but get an error of SQL syntax

```
SELECT * FROM request WHERE (MONTH(date) = MONTH(GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the statuses of the current month:

```
SELECT
    status
    COUNT(*)
FROM request
WHERE
    MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY status
```

To get next month's I would use:

```
SELECT
    status,
    COUNT(*)
FROM request
WHERE
    MONTH(date) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY status
```

We take the last day of the current month and add 1. Just to avoid using things like `MONTH(NOW())+1` or `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: i recieve an error  In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column i used SELECT status,COUNT(*) FROM request WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW());

Comment: Ahh of course, forgot to add the GROUP BY it's added now

Answer (score 0):

`GETDATE()` is a SQL Server function.  Perhaps it will work with the MySQL function:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM request r
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(now());
```

If this works, realize that it only refers to the calendar month in any year.  It is not necessarily the current month.

Comment: It works how can query those only status with pending it gives me an error. I used WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(now()) AND status = Pending; and how can I query the incoming month or the next month. I want to be able to dynamically query the next month only example: current month is october I just want the values for the month of november,